# ERROR- :8080/:1 GET http://localhost:8080/ 404 (OK)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have created a simple server at port 8080 and using three.js to load a GLTF file in my HTML document. Here is the server side code and then the HTML code.

```js
var http= require('http');
var fs = require('fs');


http.createServer(function(req,res){
  res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'text/html'})
  fs.readFile('1.html',function(error,data){
    if(error){
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.write('FILE CANNOT BE FOUND'+error)
    }
    else{
      res.write(data)
    }
    res.end()
  })
}).listen(8080,function(error){
  if(error){
    console.log('Somenthing went wrong'+error)
  }else{
    console.log('Server is setup');
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=UTF-8
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader2.js">

    </script>
    <script src="1.js"></script>
    <script type="module">

    import {GLTFLoader} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

      let scene, camera, renderer;

      function init() {

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,1,5000);
        camera.rotation.y = 45/180*Math.PI;
        camera.position.x = 800;
        camera.position.y = 100;
        camera.position.z = 1000;



        const hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight (0x404040,100);
        scene.add(hlight);

        const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff,100);
        directionalLight.position.set(0,1,0);
        directionalLight.castShadow = true;
        scene.add(directionalLight);
        const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
        light.position.set(0,300,500);
        scene.add(light);
        const light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
        light2.position.set(500,100,0);
        scene.add(light2);
        const light3 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
        light3.position.set(0,100,-500);
        scene.add(light3);
        const light4 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
        light4.position.set(-500,300,500);
        scene.add(light4);

        var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

    loader.load( 'model.gltf', function ( gltf ) {

     scene.add( gltf.scene );

    }, undefined, function ( error ) {

     console.error( error );

    } );

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


      }
      function animate() {
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }
      init();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Now getting error-**:8080/:1 GET http://localhost:8080/ 404 (OK)** 
>   Both my file named as 1.js and 1.html.
>
> Also, there are 2 warnings with it-
>
> **DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map:
>   HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME**
>
> **DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
>   chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.postload.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME**
>
> Even I have tried it with object file too. Same errors are shown.

Comment: Those last 2 warnings are not relevant. They are from a chrome extension. In your code it says the server is listening on 8000, not 8080. Maybe that's the problem? In that case the url should be `http://localhost:8000/1.html` and maybe `<script src="./1.js"></script>`

Comment: @EthanHermsey I have checked that too. Still it's not working.Still showing- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK)

Comment: `fs.readFile('1.html',function(error,data)` this line is probably throwing an error. Currently the error handler returns a 404 but does not log the error. Adding, `console.error(error)` will probably reveal the underlying issue.

Comment: @Boaz-ReinstateMonica console.error(error) shows (VM90:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: error is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:15)  also the page is showing FILE CANNOT BE FOUND

Comment: @prinzu Is the first error from the server console or the browser?

Comment: @Boaz-ReinstateMonica after setting server and then going to http://localhost:8080/  gives FILE CANNOT BE FOUND and the  if i write  console.error(error) then it shows (VM90:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: error is not defined at <anonymous>:1:15).It is from browser console.

Comment: @prinzu The error is occurring on the server. It’s currently not being returned to the browser at all. You can log it in the error handler in the Node.js script and/or return it to the browser.

Comment: fs.readFile('1.html',function(error,data){
    if(error){
      res.writeHead(404);
      console.log(error);
      res.write('FILE CANNOT BE FOUND');
    }
    else{
      res.write(data)
    }  Like this?? This is not showing any error anywhere. @Boaz-ReinstateMonica

Comment: @prinzu Where is the server script being run? For example, if it's run in a terminal, the error should appear there.

Comment: I am currently using atom and its inbuilt Command prompt. That is only showing that "Server is setup".@Boaz-ReinstateMonica

Comment: @prinzu And the `console.error(error)` was added there?

Comment: @Boaz-ReinstateMonica yes sir. well I have done as gman  in the ans has told me, then got no errors. but the browser is showing="This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at http://localhost:8080/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That server at best serves a single file.

Any reason you're writing your own server?

In any case if you want to write your own server you need to read the file requested, not just `1.html` and you need to send the correct mime type which I hacked in but you really need to use [a library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types) because there are 100s of mime types

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

const basePath = process.cwd();
const mimeTypes = {
  '.html': 'text/html',
  '.js': 'application/javascript',
  '.jpg': 'image/jpeg',
  '.png': 'image/jpeg',
};

http.createServer(function(req, res){
  const filename = `${basePath}${url.parse(req.url).pathname}`;
  fs.readFile(filename, function(error, data) {
    if(error){
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end(`FILE ${filename} CANNOT BE FOUND ${error}`);
      return;
    }
    const mimeType = mimeTypes[path.extname(filename)];
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': mimeType || 'application/octet-stream'});
    res.end(data);
  })
}).listen(8080, function(error) {
  if (error){
    console.log('Something went wrong:', error);
  } else {
    console.log('Server is setup');
  }
});
```

Most people don't write their own server, they use [an existing one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/servez) and even if they are writing their own they use [a library](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) because there are a ton of subtle things that need to be handled like sending the correct mime type, handling CORS, dealing with OPTIONS and HEAD requests, streaming the result because you don't really want to load a gigabyte video into memory with `fs.readFile`, and other things.

Comment: Thanks for that sir. Now i got no errors,but still  it is not showing anything on browser and instead showing-"This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at http://localhost:8080/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."